# Is Node.Js compatible with iPhone Objective C development for apps?

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, objective-c, node.js

I am a designer interested in making a shift to iPhone App Development. I am looking to spend the weeks after my exams studying how backend and frontend iPhone development works.

If I want to ultimately build an app which requires a frontend work in ObjectiveC/Xcode environment will I be able to use Node.js for example to compile user data and databases for backend data?

As I understand it (please correct me if I am wrong) to do an app which connects to servers for data requests you need a backend development. I have been reading about node.js and it seems very fast and its javascript which I like.

What would be the easiest combo to get into. I really am not technical and want to limit the pain for compatibility issues.

Will Objective C and Node.js be compatible?
Do you have any outside recommendations with experience you like to share?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, any web server that has the ability to accept http requests and respond with some content (JSON, XML, HTML, string...) will work, you just have to use the correct methods for submitting the request and parsing the response.

Personally, I've been using node.js for an API that I created and host it on AWS. It's lightning fast and I've had no issues. As with most programming languages today, objective-c has libraries that allow you to submit http requests and parse JSON responses.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js supply web interface just like any other backend stack you can choose, so it is suitable for iPhone backend development.

You can also skip the entire backend development, hosting solution and DNS boilerplate if you wish, by using backend as a service solutions like Parse or Stackmob